# How to set time zone to UTC?

Tags: macos, timezone

I prefer my time zone to be UTC.  While I could simply choose my location as Reykjavik, Iceland, for which the official time is UTC, I would much rather have a way to use UTC without changing my location setting that way.  Is this possible?  I'm on Lion if that matters.

Comment: Your location and time zone settings are linked. You have to choose a location to change your time zone. But why won’t you like to change your location? It just changes in the time zone settings, not anywhere else.

Comment: So if I do this, I won't suddenly find that documents, videos, images, etc. that I create have metadata that says I live in Reykjavik?

Comment: No, they use the data in your Contact Card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your location and time zone settings are linked. You have to choose a location to change your time zone. This doesn’t affect your location in your documents or Autofill, as those use the data from your Contact Card.

Comment: Would you prefer an upvote or an increased chance at Tenacious badge :-)

Comment: Well of course a chance at Tenacious :)